# WooCommerce Call to a member function get_type() on bool

Tags: woocommerce

After updating a plugin on my website, I am getting a fatal error `Call to a member function get_type() on bool`

```
/* WooCommerece settings */
if ( defined( 'WOOCOMMERCE_VERSION' ) && isset( $query_post_type ) && $query_post_type == 'product' ) {
    if ( function_exists( 'wc_get_product' ) ) {
        // WC 3.0+
        $woo_product = wc_get_product( $post->ID );
        $woo_is_variation = $woo_product->get_type() == 'variable' ? true : false;
    } else {
        // Old WC
        $woo_product = get_product( $post->ID );
        $woo_is_variation = isset( $woo_product->product_type ) && ( $woo_product->product_type == 'variation' || $woo_product->product_type == 'variable' ) ? true : false;
        if ( $woo_is_variation ) {$post = $woo_product->post;}
    }
}
```

I have tried modifying the code to

```
if( $product->is_type('variable') ) :
    $woo_is_variation = true;
else :
    $woo_is_variation = false;
endif;
```

I have reached out to the plugin author but so far I have had no response.

My product page is down and would appreciate some help with this.

Comment: please share the full code. also, where are you putting this code? and what you want to achieve?

Comment: Code updated but the plugin I am using is over 3,000 lines so I am trying to include the relevant code. Judging by the code, it's trying to determine if a WooCommerce product is a variable product or not.

Comment: usually, this error means your $woo_product variable is empty. did you try to debug and check what is inside $woo_product?

Comment: I did dump the content of $woo_product and it has a lot of data, for example object(WC_Product_Simple)...

Comment: Could really use some help with this.

Comment: I have to check and therefore I need site admin and server access.